# Grab rss feed with php and change value in rss string

Tags: php, rss, yahoo-finance

Ok I have a site where I use this code to grab the stock quote for each stock searched. `<?php echo $_GET['quote'];?>` What i'm trying to do is to display RSS news data by using this code below:

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=GOOG&region=US&lang=en-USsto');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array (
    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
    array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 5;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

Do you see the "GOOG" section? that is what I'm trying to change dynamically with the quote capture code `<?php echo $_GET['quote'];?>` and it throws errors! Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: what was the code you were using to change it and what was the errors you were getting

Comment: I used this: `http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=<?php echo $_GET['quote'];?>&region=US&lang=en-USsto` do you see the `<?php echo $_GET['quote'];?>` added to the string? that was creating an error when I tested it live

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your GET value contains a legitimate ticker code then this would work.

```
$rss->load('http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s='.$_GET['quote'].'&region=US&lang=en-USsto');
```

You are already in a php context so  is not the way to concatenate a string

This is however not a robust way to handle it as there is no checking that $_GET['quote'] is set or has any value, you would need to decide what to get if it was not set

**UPDATE**

NB the original URL given in the question is invalid

```
http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=GOOG&region=US&lang=en-USsto
```

does not work but

```
http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=GOOG&region=US&lang=en-US
```

does

So please update your code to

```
$rss->load('http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s='.$_GET['quote'].'&region=US&lang=en-US');
```

Comment: ok awesome that worked because it shows the pulled stock quote I wanted to view but now it shows an error for this `$rss = new DOMDocument();` i'm running the php code on a regular php site not through wordpress any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: It would help if you described what the error you were getting was. "It shows an error" does not help anyone to help you

Comment: very true sorry! here is the error that was shown `Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=bbry&region=US&lang=en-USsto) [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 502 Server Hangup in /home/mysite/mysitedotcom.com/quotes/index.php on line 175`

Comment: And what happens when you request that URL in your browser

Comment: when i request the yahoo finance url it says "server hangup" what does that mean for the code? I copy the url from my code and it does the hang up whereas if i type it in then the link works fine

Comment: It means there is nothing wrong with your code as that is what is happening on their server. The problem is actually with the URL you are requesting. You get the same when requesting http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=GOOG&region=US&lang=en-USsto. Probably something to do with the random "sto" on the end of the url in your  code sample

Comment: I think you will find the answer is to remove the sto from the end of your URL, so http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=GOOG&region=US&lang=en-US instead of http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=GOOG&region=US&lang=en-USsto as that url you have given in your code does not even work.